# Add multiples of <tr> id value from jstl core

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I have a servlet that returns me the items `${bookList}`. This contains the id, name and created date of all books.
So inside my table body, I want users to be able to click either the name or the created date to retrieve specific Book. How to I add the `<c:out value="${book.id }"/>` inside the `<tr id="">` so that I can add an JQuery event to detect any click and get the id of the book?

```
<tbody id="booktablebody">  
    <c:forEach items="${bookList}" var ="book">
        <tr id="'"+<c:out value="${book.id }"/>+"'">
            <td><c:out value="${book.bookName}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${book.createdDate }" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>    
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as follows:

```
<tr data-book-id="<c:out value="${book.id}"/>">
    <td><c:out value="${book.bookName}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${book.createdDate }" /></td>
</tr>
```

Get tr's id with jQuery

`data-book-id` is equal `data('bookId')` on the jQuery side.

```
$("#booktablebody").on('click','tr',function(){
  var id = $(this).data('bookId');
});
```